# Ubuntu 18.04 sometimes logouts instead of shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

When I press shut down, it sometimes logouts instead. After that, I have to login again. Shortly after the desktop appears again, whole screen goes black and there is only a white blinking underscore in the top left corner. After that, nothing more seem to happen. I don't know how long this lasts for, I never had more than a few minutes. (When I am in haste, I really don't want to wait for such things.) I always turned it off by holding the power button when this appeared.

Is there any way to remove this "feature"? It is annoying.

Comment: Just to get an idea of whether it's the GUI or the underlying mechanism, can you try doing `sudo shutdown -h now` from the command line when you want to shut down? Does that work or still the same problem?

Comment: The bug does not happen always, so I'll do this until I observe it again.